# delphi class determined at runtime

Tags: delphi, types

Is there a way in Delphi XE+ to create a function whose result is determined at runtime?

For example:

```
function ARuntimeClass(achoice: integer): ClassType;
begin
   case achoice of
     0: Result := TEdit;
     1: Result := TMemo;
     2: Result := TCheckbox;
     3: Result := TComboBox;
   end;
end;
```

Then, at runtime:

```
var
  aComponent: TComponent;       
begin
  aComponent := FindComponent('SomeComponent234');
  //then process
  ARuntimeClass(2).Checked := True;
  aComponent := FindComponent('SomeComponent123');
  //then process
  ARuntimeClass(0).Text := 'Chosen';    
end;
```

I am trying to typecast at runtime.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. Your `ARuntimeClass` returns *metaclasses* (like `TEdit`), but the rest of your code seems to assume that it returns actual objects (instances).

Comment: Also, I don't see what the `aComponent` lines have to do with the `ARuntimeClass` lines.

Comment: That's my goal, i'm not sure it can be done. For example, User selects a TEdit on a screen, so I want to adjust its Text property, but I won't know which component will be selected, and different components have different properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can return a *class type* as a function result, using a metaclass type like [`System.TClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TClass) (represents all class types), [`Classes.TComponentClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponentClass) (represents classes derived from `TComponent`), [`TControlClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControlClass) (represents all classes derived from `TControl`), etc.

```pascal
function ARuntimeClass(achoice: integer): TControlClass;
begin
  case achoice of
    0: Result := TEdit;
    1: Result := TMemo;
    2: Result := TCheckbox;
    3: Result := TComboBox;
  end;
end;
```

Although, you can simply use [`aComponent.ClassType()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.ClassType) instead to access the object's real metaclass type, you don't need a separate function for that.

However, just having access to a metaclass type doesn't actually solve your issue.  You can't use a metaclass to typecast an object pointer to access any type-specific members.  For what you are attempting, you need to [use RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_RTTI) instead, eg:

Using old-style RTTI (pre-D2010):

```pascal
uses
  ..., TypInfo;

var
  aComponent: TComponent;       
  aProp: PPropInfo;
begin
  aComponent := FindComponent('SomeComponent234');
  //then process
  pProp := GetPropInfo(aComponent, 'Checked');
  if aProp <> nil then SetOrdProp(aComponent, aProp, True);

  aComponent := FindComponent('SomeComponent123');
  //then process
  aProp := GetPropInfo(aComponent, 'Text');
  if aProp = nil then aProp := GetPropInfo(aComponent, 'Caption');
  if aProp <> nil then SetStrProp(aComponent, aProp, 'Chosen');
end;
```

Using new-style enhanced RTTI (D2010+):

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.Rtti;

var
  aComponent: TComponent;       
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  rType: TRttiType;
  rProp: TRttiProperty;
begin
  aComponent := FindComponent('SomeComponent234');
  //then process
  rType := ctx.GetType(aComponent.ClassType);
  rProp := rType.GetProperty('Checked');
  if rProp <> nil then rProp.SetValue(aComponent, True);

  aComponent := FindComponent('SomeComponent123');
  //then process
  rType := ctx.GetType(aComponent.ClassType);
  rProp := rType.GetProperty('Text');
  if rProp = nil then rProp := rType.GetProperty('Caption');
  if rProp <> nil then rProp.SetValue(aComponent, 'Chosen');
end;
```

Comment: Why you could not use metaclass type to typecast an object pointer to access any type-specific members?

Comment: @SilverWarior Because that is simply not how the Pascal language works. Typecasts have to be known at compile-time so the compiler can emit the proper codegen for them. Variables used to hold metaclass types are not known until runtime and thus cannot be used in typecasts.

Comment: So what using [Class operators like is Operator and as Operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Class_References#The_is_Operator) can't be used for typecasting? This operators existed in pascal language for ever and have been used for typecasting for as long even before RTTI existed. of course unlike RTTI class operators don't offer any safeguards so you can easily typecast your object as wrong class and wreck havoc by doing so. Which is why many people avoid using them.

Comment: Thank you Remy. This seems like what I need.

Comment: Sounds like this technology could also be used as a Property Editor in RunTime...

Comment: @douglaskeene yes. Property editors, both design-time and run-time, are based on RTTI.

Comment: @SilverWarior `is` is not a typecast, it queries if an object supports a particular class type. `as` is a typecast. But you can't pass a *variable* holding a class type to either of them, ie `var cls: TControlClass; cls := TEdit; if obj is cls then (obj as cls).Text := '...';` doesn't work. The compiler validates the parameters at compile-time (and `Text` is not a public property of `TControl`). But `if obj is TEdit then (obj as TEdit).Text := '...';` works fine. "*class operators don't offer any safeguards*" - the `as` operator raises an exception if the cast fails. That is a safeguard.